# Active services (ports) using sockets

Tags: c, sockets, unix, port

I´m going to program an application that shows if there is an active/inactive service in a range of UDP ports, of a given IP.

My first intention it's trying to bind a socket with an address (the port is included in the address). Bind will return -1 if fails, with an errno EADDRINUSE, that means that the specified address is already in use. If the bind is done, I will close the socket, and go to the next port.

I'm a bit lost with sockets and networks things, so I would like to know if my approach is correct, or a clue about the best way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on operating system, there are often other methods to find out the ports in use (for Linux, for example, you could look at the netstat source).

Comment: you can have multiple connections, so your approach won't work.

Comment: On Windows, you can use [`GetUdpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366033.aspx) and [`GetUdp6Table()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408407.aspx).

Comment: Wasn't netstat a command for the command line terminal? How could I use it in a C program?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use [`GetUdpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366033.aspx) and [`GetUdp6Table()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408407.aspx) to ask the OS for a list of active IPv4/IPv6 UDP sockets (there are corresponding functions for TCP sockets).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using the socket API for Unix

Comment: Anyway, +1, because I will maybe use it in the future. Sorry for double-posting

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, the `/proc/net/udp` file lists all open UDP sockets. The 2nd column in the file shows the interface address and port number (in hex):

```
[root@localhost ~]# head -n 2 /proc/net/udp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
  33: 00000000:00A1 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 9236 2 ffff8102205a8980
```

Alternatively you can run `netstat -au` (on POSIX systems you can use the `popen()` system call to run a program and capture its output as a `FILE *`):

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -au
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
udp        0      0 *:snmp                      *:*
```

Your `bind()` technique is not reliable because UDP allows multple bound sockets to the same addresses (depending on socket settings).

Comment: I will try to use this one, but I think that it should be a better/easier way, just like the Windows one. And thanks for the bind explanation.

Comment: @TitoMc I didn't design UNIX/Linux :) It is true that the Windows API was designed using a very very different philosophy from Linux/UNIX. I will not attempt to attack or defend either.